# Как отправить файл с помощью smtplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, gmail, smtplib

Мне нужно отправить файл с помощью smtplib gmail, нужен как можно меньше код, чтобы можно было запросто его понять и использовать.

Comment: какие-нибудь еще пожелания может быть?)

Comment: @МихаилРебров как для ребенка)

Comment: Кажется, для простоты, стоит обратиться к псевдокоду)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В интернете нашёл код:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders


SUBJECT = "Email Data"

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT 
msg['From'] = self.EMAIL_FROM
msg['To'] = ', '.join(self.EMAIL_TO)

part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open("text.txt", "rb").read())
Encoders.encode_base64(part)

part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="text.txt"')

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP(self.EMAIL_SERVER)
server.sendmail(self.EMAIL_FROM, self.EMAIL_TO, msg.as_string())
```

Взял тут - https://www.it-swarm.com.ru/ru/python/kak-otpravit-vlozheniya-elektronnoi-pochty/969524676/